# M-files problem on Ubuntu need help for beginner

Tags: software-installation

I just switch to my main desktop windows 10 to Ubuntu 18.10.
It is faster, and I like it. But I could not use my regular programme especially M-files(document management system). I found something about it on this address 
https://archive.codeplex.com/?p=mfilesfs
However,  I am a beginner user of Ubuntu. Do you know how I can install and use this M-files programme?

Thanks in advance

Comment: According to the company's website, Linux and macOS are only supported via a web interface: [System Requirements](https://www.m-files.com/user-guide/latest/eng/System_requirements.html)

Comment: Moreover, the Linux interface seems to have had little development since [it's release in 2010](https://community.m-files.com/index.php?topic=562.0)

Comment: Thank you for your reply and interest.  Yes, you are right it can work via the web interface. However, ıt shows only files. You can not change on the web interface. on the other hand, ı downloaded the mentioned app but I do not know to run it (https://archive.codeplex.com/?p=mfilesfs) do you know how can I run this?

Comment: This question is off topic as non-reproducible because it has been abandoned.